# Javascript is it bad to replace a function with bound version of itself

Tags: javascript, function, binding

I have a react component that has to pass a method to its children so that they can modify the state. So I created a function that allows to do that. I know I should bind the parent component to the `this` parameter of the function so that the children can successfully modify the state. The reason I want to do this is silly: I just don't know what to name the bound version ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. So what wanted to do is:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.modifyState = this.modifyState.bind(this);
    }

    modifyState() { /* blah blah*/ }

    render() {
        return(
            <Child modifyState={this.modifyState} />
        );
    }
}
```

Now my question is:
Is there a reason why I really don't want to do this, can it cause any problems?

The reason I ask is, if there were no downsides, why not have this be the default behavior of it, in other languages `this` is always an instance of the class where the function (method) is defined. If you wanted the current behavior (`this` is the object who called the function from my understanding) just declare a global function.

Comment: The reasons for the current behavior are historical. If we would invent `this` today it would probably work different.

Comment: I get that, the part on the `this` behavior was just an opinion. The real question is: should I do it or not?

Comment: You can. You dont have to. Sometimes you have to. It kind of depends. Thats *really* opinion based. Some like this, others dont.

Comment: Opinion based? Well I suppose if that is the case then there are no significant side effects or downsides on replacing the function. I thought that like so many other seemingly  "harmless" things the answer was "you can but shouldn't because it also does this other bad thing."